# Error in angular development packages on doing an ng version

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli

When I do ng --version I get the following output:

```
Angular CLI: 10.2.0
Node: 12.16.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: <error>
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: No

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1002.0 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/build-angular      <error>
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   <error>
@angular-devkit/core               10.2.0 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics         10.2.0 (cli-only)
@angular/cli                       10.2.0 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular                10.2.0 (cli-only)
@schematics/update                 0.1002.0 (cli-only)
ng-packagr                         <error>
rxjs                               6.6.2 (cli-only)
typescript                         3.7.2 (cli-only)
```

Can someone help me with it? What has gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was npm install, but npm install was giving me

```
npm - tarball data for @npm6.1.4 seems to be corrupted
```

To solve this problem I did the following:

1. Removed the node_modules folder
2. Deleted the package-lock.json file
3. npm update
4. npm install (went through fine)

Got rid of the development errors on doing an ng version